# Continue checking and returning for more matches in foreach if statement

Tags: php, function, loops, if-statement, foreach

I have a function that is essentially going through a CSV file, and finding rows that match up with a user's settings in their profile. Anyway...

The issue is that I'm checking through the CSV file for each car (row), and then returning the value if the car matches the user's setting. The issue is, if a user has a setting for the following:

- Honda Civic 1993 through 2007
- Jeep Liberty 2002 through 2018

And the CSV has records of:

- Honda Civic 1996
- Honda Civic 2004
- Jeep Liberty 2010

... currently the `if` statement will only return the first iteration of the Honda Civic, before it then returns the Jeep Liberty. So it never knows to move to the next / subsequent matches of the `if` statement.

```
    private function find_vehicle($cars,$make,$model,$yr_start,$yr_end){
        $tmp = explode("|", $model);
        $model = $tmp[1];
        echo 'Looking for: ' . $make . ' '. $model . ' between: '.$yr_start .'-'.$yr_end . '<br>';
        foreach ( $cars as $car ) {
            if ($make == $car[1] && $model == $car[2]){
                if ($car[4] >= $yr_start && $car[4] <= $yr_end){
                    return $car;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

How can I adjust the `foreach` and/or `if` statement, so that it will not stop at the first version of a Make/Model/Year... but that it will continue to `return` each match as a new `$car`?

Otherwise, currently the output is:

- Honda Civic 1996
- Jeep Liberty 2010

But I need it to also return the other matching Honda Civic 2004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your function into a generator (see PHP Generators Overview https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php):

```
private function find_vehicle($cars,$make,$model,$yr_start,$yr_end) {
    $tmp = explode("|", $model);
    $model = $tmp[1];
    echo 'Looking for: ' . $make . ' '. $model . ' between: '.$yr_start .'-'.$yr_end . '<br>';
    foreach ( $cars as $car ) {
        if ($make == $car[1] && $model == $car[2]){
            if ($car[4] >= $yr_start && $car[4] <= $yr_end){
                yield $car;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
foreach (find_vehicle($cars, $make, $model, $yr_start, $yr_end) as $car) {
    // Do something with $car
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get this to work, within the following Gist? https://gist.github.com/Garconis/6154c0c9a3a1209773d19e132e789bab

Comment: Looking at line 166 of that Gist, you would use the above Generator like:
`foreach ($this->find_vehicle($cars, $make, $model, $year_start, $year_end) as $car) {
    array_push($vehicles, $car);
}`

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to build an array for the matching cars, and return this list at the end of the function (some comments in the code)...

```
private function find_vehicle($cars,$make,$model,$yr_start,$yr_end){
    $tmp = explode("|", $model);
    $model = $tmp[1];
    // List of matching records
    $matching = [];
    // echo 'Looking for: ' . $make . ' '. $model . ' between: '.$yr_start .'-'.$yr_end . '<br>';
    foreach ( $cars as $car ) {
        if ($make == $car[1] && $model == $car[2]){
            if ($car[4] >= $yr_start && $car[4] <= $yr_end){
                // Add new entry to matching list (rather than return the first one)
                $matching[] = $car;
            }
        }
    }
    return $matching;
}
```

This uses `$matching` to keep a list, adding to it using

```
$matching[] = $car;
```

At the end it passes this back, it will be an empty list if nothing is found

```
return $matching;
```

As you can also see I've commented out the `echo` - it's useful for debugging, but try and avoid methods that both process data and produce output unless you have to.

Comment: Looks like this now causes the output to be two `Array` and a blank:
 -  Array 
 -  Array 
 -

Comment: The difference is that now your output is an array of matches whereas before you were getting 1 returned value.  So you either need to do a `foreach` over the results of whatever method your using need to be in some form of loop.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your answer, so that the output of `$car` is still each individual record/value? The `$car` variable is used throughout the rest of the document, and I think it expects it to be a single car, not an array. For example: https://d.pr/free/i/YfshKb and https://d.pr/free/i/8UnUMK

Comment: Not sure how I can return a list of cars as 1 car, this is contradicting what your asking for.

Comment: Ah, well, in the original code example, it was creating a $car for each match (unless it was the same make/model). But the $car wasn't an array. Now with your code, the $car result is an array, and I'm not sure how to get the value of each one... so that other uses of the $car variable can make use of it.

Comment: If it helps, here is a Gist of the PHP file. You were helping with the function on line 28. But now that causes issues with other stuff, since it's not expecting $car to be an array: https://gist.github.com/Garconis/6154c0c9a3a1209773d19e132e789bab